# Why is my setStateAction not updating with json response data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, asynchronous, github-api

I am trying to fetch user data using the GitHub API, but when I make a request using fetch() the request is not sent until after the return(). The response data will only show after the page loads, but I need it before render to use as HTML parameters. I know it has something to do with JSON requests being asynchronous, but I'm not sure how to change the code to set the data properly.

```
const user = params.get("user");
const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null);
const [reqLimit, setReqLimit] = useState(null);

const getUserData = () => {
    fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${user}`)
      .then(response => {response.json();})
      .then(json => console.log(json))//'undefined'
      .then(json => setUserData(json))
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
      });
};

useMemo(() => {
    fetch(`https://api.github.com/rate_limit`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
            setReqLimit(json.resources.core);
            if (json.resources.core.remaining < 1) {
                console.error('Error:', 40
            }
        });

    getUserData();
}, [userData]);

return (
    <main>
    //userData = null; (Why?)
    </main>
)
```

Comment: .then(json => console.log(json))//'undefined'
return the json here to appear in then

Answer (score 0):

```
fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${user}`)
      .then(response => response.json();) // return json
      //.then(json => console.log(json))//'undefined' remove this from here
      .then(json => setUserData(json))
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
      });
```

Comment: So why is it that the fetch for the rate_limit api worked without needing to return the response?

Comment: .then(response => response.json()) this way you convert response to json then return it but that way      .then(response => {response.json();}) you dont return anything. the same for log, you just log without return anything next chain